# add screenshots with specific name to allure report

Tags: javascript, automated-tests, webdriver, mocha.js, allure

I'm learning webdriverIO and I have a question.
Can we take screenshots with testcase's name and date? Now my screenshots name are something like this "e3e4c61d-88c2-4388-bc08-1247feea6d44-attachment.png". I use mocha framework and allure reporter.
Maybe anyone know where I can see some docs or examples?